# Equivalent code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can some one suggest equivalent code in python for below line

```
UInt32.Parse(("000000" + hexfileln.Substring(1, 2)), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is pointless to prefix a hex number with zeros. Ignoring that, and noting that the `int` constructor accepts a string argument and the base, you can use `int` to parse a hexadecimal number:

```
int(hexfileln[1:3], 16)
```